# How to set the formatting on the axes in Google Charts to a certain pattern?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to change the formatting of the values on the **axis** to look like so:

```
1
100
1 000
10 000
100 000
1 000 000
```

Meaning, I'd like to change the default grouping symbol to a space (' '). So far I tried with different approaches but none of them worked. Even the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats) couldn't help me much. Anyone?

**Important:**

1. I want to change the formatting on the values on the axis, not the inner values.
2. I don't want to change the language of the google chart.

Comment: This is a typical approach of presuming you know better than your users. You don't. the [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) is what is best since it will use the clients preferred number format

Comment: @Endless thanks, but I would say that, first, it's not a decision that I've made, second, obviously it's not an answer to the question and third, I can hardly believe that most of the users (except for the developers and geeks) would actually know how to change the formatting on their PCs.

Comment: The typical user wouldn't care of changing the formatting on their PCs since it would probably already be preconfigure with what the user want to have based on there country/language settings

Comment: Okay, so it seems like you are going to change the minds of my colleagues. Till then, do you plan to give an answer to the question?

Comment: nope, never worker with google charts so don't know much about it

Comment: Okay, it was nice having a philosophical debate with you ;)

Comment: After some reading in the docs, the source and a few experiments I'd say that it is not supported. And I didn't even find an easy way to hack into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use option --> `ticks` -- to provide custom labels for either axis

`hAxis` or `vAxis`

using object notation, provide both a value `v:` and a formatted value `f:`

```
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: '1'},
        {v: 1, f: '100'},
        {v: 2, f: '1 000'},
        {v: 3, f: '10 000'},
        {v: 4, f: '100 000'},
        {v: 5, f: '1 000 000'}
      ]
    },
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [5, 5],
    [6, 6]
  ]);
  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: '1'},
        {v: 1, f: '100'},
        {v: 2, f: '1 000'},
        {v: 3, f: '10 000'},
        {v: 4, f: '100 000'},
        {v: 5, f: '1 000 000'}
      ]
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: '1'},
        {v: 1, f: '100'},
        {v: 2, f: '1 000'},
        {v: 3, f: '10 000'},
        {v: 4, f: '100 000'},
        {v: 5, f: '1 000 000'}
      ]
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

**EDIT**

you can use a number formatter to create the number pattern

```
var formatLabel = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  groupingSymbol: ' ',
  fractionDigits: 0
});
```

format the data table to see the format on the tooltips

```
// format tooltips
formatLabel.format(data, 1);
```

still need to create custom labels to see on the axis

```
// create axis labels
var axisTicks = [];
var axisRange = data.getColumnRange(1);
for (var i = axisRange.min; i <= axisRange.max; i=i+1000) {
  axisTicks.push({
    v: i,
    f: formatLabel.formatValue(i)
  });
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    [0, 1000],
    [1, 2000],
    [2, 3000],
    [3, 6000],
    [4, 10000]
  ]);

  var formatLabel = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    groupingSymbol: ' ',
    fractionDigits: 0
  });

  // format tooltips
  formatLabel.format(data, 1);

  // create axis labels
  var axisTicks = [];
  var axisRange = data.getColumnRange(1);
  for (var i = axisRange.min; i <= axisRange.max; i=i+1000) {
    axisTicks.push({
      v: i,
      f: formatLabel.formatValue(i)
    });
  }

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    pointSize: 4,
    vAxis: {
      ticks: axisTicks
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```