# Adding string to axis for bubble charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

This question has been answered before, but the current version does not change the x and y axis to strings appropriately. Here's the current code and a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwf0y647/):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
            packages: ['corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            //these arrays hold the label strings
            var products = new Array();
            for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                products[i] = 'product' + i;

            var customers = new Array();
            for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++)
                customers[i] = 'customer' + i;


            var options = {
                'title': 'Customer / Product Grid',
                // 'vAxis': { textPosition: 'in' },
                vAxis: {
                    viewWindow: {
                        max: products.length,
                        min: 0,
                    },
                    gridlines: {
                        count: products.length,
                        color: 'white',
                    }
                },
                hAxis: {
                    viewWindow: {
                        max: customers.length,
                        min: 0,
                    },
                    gridlines: {
                        count: customers.length,
                        color: 'white',
                    }
                },
                'width': 1000,
                'height': 500
            };

            //dtd
            var customer_product_grid_data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            customer_product_grid_data_table.addColumn('string', 'Customer and Product');
            customer_product_grid_data_table.addColumn('number', 'Customer');
            customer_product_grid_data_table.addColumn('number', 'Product');
            customer_product_grid_data_table.addColumn('number', 'Profit Margin');
            customer_product_grid_data_table.addColumn('number', 'Proportion of Sales');

            // add some random numbers to show off
            for (var i = 1; i < products.length; i++)
                for (var j = 1; j < customers.length; j++) {
                    customer_product_grid_data_table.addRow([
                        '', j, i, 50 * Math.cos(i + j), 20 * Math.sin(i)
                    ]);
                }

            var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(customer_product_grid_data_table, options);

            /*
             * This can also be 
             * text[text-anchor="start"]
             * or
             * text[text-anchor="middle"]
             * depending on the axis settings. If it doesnt work, try another one, or check the generated SVG source code in your HTML doc.
             */
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                $('#chart_div svg text[text-anchor="middle"]:contains("' + i + '")').text(function(j,t) {
                    console.log(t + " " + i);
                    if (t == i) {
                        if (i >= products.length || i < 1) {
                            return " ";
                        }
                        return products[i];
                    }
                });
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
                $('#chart_div svg text[text-anchor="middle"]:contains("' + i + '")').text(function(j, t) {
                    if (t == i) {
                        if (i >= customers.length || i < 1) {
                            return " ";
                        }
                        return customers[i];
                    }
                });


            } // end function 

        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

For some reason, it only changes the 6th product. How can I make it so that both the axis are converted into their appropriate strings?

Comment: recommend using [custom axis `ticks`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44928872/5090771), rather than trying to modify the svg manually...

Comment: @WhiteHat Would this work since Bubble Charts axis only allow for numbers and not strings?

Comment: yes, as seen in the linked answer, using object notation, provide the true axis label value for the value property (`v:`), use whatever string you want for the formatted value property (`f:`) -- e.g. for each tick -- `{v: 0, f: 'whatever 0'}`

Comment: the above doesn't work due to the number of labels vs. the array used to find them and the `text-anchor` attribute can be _start_, _middle_, or __end__ (see comment section above)

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you so much!